# Access openfire Java API through .net?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, interop, openfire

I am looking to access the openfire Java API through .net/asp.net so I can basically interface openfire and it's plugins in an asp.net web application.

I am wondering what the best way to go about accessing a Java API through .net or if someone knows of another way of using openfire with asp.net. I know that doing a conversion with sharpen would take a very long time and probably wouldn't be worth it.

Any information on this topic is good information IMO. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions available:

1. [**IKVM.NET**](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html)

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. It includes the following components:
>
> - A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> - A .NET implementation of
>     the Java class libraries
> - Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability

1. [**jni4net**](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)

> Bridge between Java and .NET (intraprocess, fast, object oriented,
>   open-source)

Comment: Hi Renat. I am going with IKVM. You really helped me out here. I can't award the bounty for two more hours but I will when I can.